# Info Template not getting displayed

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a layer like,

```
realTimeLayer = new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer();
```

I have an infoTemplate like,

```
infoTemplate=new esri.InfoTemplate("/*Content goes here*/");
```

I am creating a graphic, adding it to the layer and plotting the point like,

```
 var graphic= new esri.Graphic(candidatePoint,candidateSymbol,attr,infoTemplate);
 realTimeLayer.add(graphic);
 map.addLayer(realTimeLayer);
 points.addPoint(candidatePoint);
```

In this case the info template works fine. 
But during some other event, I am adding the graphic like

```
var graphic= new esri.Graphic(candidatePoint,candidateSymbol,attr,infoTemplate);
map.graphics.add(graphic);
points.addPoint(candidatePoint);
```

But this time, I don't get the info template in IE9 even after clicking on the push pin. What could be the reason? And how should I correct this?

Comment: Have you tested with other Browsers?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Yes. I did. Works fine with Ie7, Ie8 and Mozilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected it by,

```
1) Removing the previous layer,
2) Creating a new GraphicsLayer()
3) And adding the graphic on top of the newly created layer.
```

That is, I am not adding th graphic to the map.graphics object but to a new layer.

Code:

```
var graphic= new esri.Graphic(candidatePoint,candidateSymbol,attr,infoTemplate);
map.removeLayer(realTimeLayer);
realTimeLayer = new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer();
realTimeLayer.add(graphic);
```